# Find the polynomial p of least degree that takes these values

Tags: numerical-methods

Find the polynomial *p* of least degree that takes these values: $p(0) = 2$,
$p(2) = 4$, $p(3) = −4$, $p(5) = 82.$ Use divide differences to get the correct polynomial.
It is not necessary to write the polynomial in the standard form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^
2+· · ·.$

I am not sure how to use the **divided differences** method, the explanations I look up are all very confusing. I can't find an actual example of a problem similar like this to even mimick - or see what's going on.. Any help would be great

Comment: No idea about divided differences.  But I'd use Lagrange Interpolation for this:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: I know how to do Lagrange, not allowed to do it. Have to use divided differences. That's why the problem says specifically - divided differences..

Comment: Fair enough.  There's also this (which does use divided differences) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial

Comment: Try [Divided Differences](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture17.pdf), page 3-4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a shot at this question...

You have four points, so we need a third-degree polynomial, $p_3(x)$.

We have $p(0)=2$, $p(2)=4$, $p(3)=-4$ and $p(5)=82$.

Calculating the divided differences...

$$p[0,2]=\frac{p(2)-p(0)}{2-0}=\frac{2}{2}=1$$
$$p[2,3]=\frac{p(3)-p(2)}{3-2}=\frac{-8}{1}=-8$$
$$p[3,5]=\frac{p(5)-p(3)}{5-3}=\frac{86}{2}=43$$
$$p[0,2,3]=\frac{p[2,3]-p[0,2]}{3-0}=\frac{-9}{3}=-3$$
$$p[2,3,5]=\frac{p[3,5]-p[2,3]}{5-2}=\frac{51}{3}=17$$
$$p[0,2,3,5]=\frac{p[2,3,5]-p[0,2,3]}{5-0}=\frac{20}{5}=4$$

The resulting polynomial should be...
$$p_3(x)=2+1(x-0)-3x(x-2)+4x(x-2)(x-3)$$

Verifying...
$$p_3(0)=2\,\checkmark$$
$$p_3(2)=2+2=4\,\checkmark$$
$$p_3(3)=2+3-3(3)(1)=-4\,\checkmark$$
$$p_3(5)=2+5-3(5)(3)+4(5)(3)(2)=82\,\checkmark$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $p[0,2,3,5]$ ?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm fixing it...

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it via reading my textbook. Working it out then will be back to mark your answer as a solution or not.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim. Would you mind checking out my attempt at another problem similar to this? [Interpolating via Newton Polynomials][1].  [1]:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460358/having-trouble-interpolating-a-polynomial-using-newtons-method

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 2$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 5$ and $y_k = p(x_k)$ for $k = 0,1,\dots,5$. The Newton polynomial $p$ is
$$ 
  P(x) = [y_0] + [y_0,y_1](x-x_0) + \cdots + [y_0,\ldots,y_4](x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_3)
$$
where the divided differences can be put in tabular form as shown on
 [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Example):

```
0   2 
        1
2   4      -3
       -8      4
3  -4      17
       43
5  82
```

Finally, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
  p(x) &= 2 + x - 3x(x-2) + 4x(x-2)(x-3) \\
       &= 4x^3 - 23x^2 + 31x + 2.
\end{align*}
$$